# TFS 2017 missing process link

Tags: tfs

Our IT installed TFS 2017 (15.112.26307.0).  It's a clean installation.  It currently has few startup projects, just to see and explorer features.  But the projects are missing "Process" link under Project Template page, to configure Agile/Scrum/CMMI.  I don't see link for "Configure Features" either.  My account has Project Administrator and Project Collection Administrators privileges.  Ultimately we would like to explorer Agile process.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you solve this issue? Regarding witadmin, you can refer to this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work

Answer (score 0):

The Process tab is something that Microsoft has been building for VSTS and which is likely to come to on-prem in the near future. But for now TFS still uses the old XML based work item templates which offer a higher level of customizability, but which are also much harder to maintain.

For specific guidance on using witadmin.exe check out:

> **TFS Process Template Customisation Guide**
>
> [Practical guidance for Work Item Tracking](https://vsardata.blob.core.windows.net/projects/TFS%20Process%20Template%20%20Customization%20Guidance.pdf) (WIT) and Process Template customizations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Ultimately we would like to customize the template, for example to add additional state, how do I go about uploading a default template or perhaps make small change and upload again?  Thanks

Comment: Witadmin.exe is your friend. There is a lot of guidance on customizing the tfs process templates available know msdn.

Comment: Ok, let me research that.  Thanks again.,